# Accidentally did a branch origin set up to track local branch

Tags: git

I accidentally did:

```
git checkout mybranch
git branch --set-upstream origin mybranch
```

Git says:

```
Branch origin set up to track local branch mybranch.
```

How do I reset that and what could it do to me?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all else fails, just edit `.git/config` with text editor. All the command does is set there

```
[branch "origin"]
merge=refs/heads/mybranch
```

so just remove the invalid setting.

Comment: nano ~/.git/config + the above worked fine. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

That means you just have a local branch that is set to be tracking the remote branch with the same name. No harm in having that, you are not forced to use the remote branch;)

You can remove the tracking link with

```
--no-track
```

or delete the remote branch:

```
git push origin :branch-name
```

For the latter, if you want to, you need to specifically remove the branch with the -d option.